# Aptana Studio 3 Freezes While Trying to Find Methods on Auto Complete

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, aptana

I am using Aptana Studio 3 for rails development, it freezes every 10 minutes. 
When I typed "." after an object (especially after Hashes), it stucks.

I checked Activity Monitor and Aptana uses over 100% CPU and never comes back to normal, till I Force Quit.

Anyone knows any workaround?

Comment: *my* workaround is RubyMine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using RubyMine after these kind of problems.  (thanks to Mark Thomas)
It's been about 1 year, without any major problem.